# The matrix of a linear transformation related to differentiaion

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

> $Trig_N$ is the complex vector space of trigonometric polynomials of degree $\le$ N, i.e. the space of functions f of the form $f(t) = \sum_{|n|\le N} a_ne^{int} $, $a_n \in C$. Let $D : f \to f'$ be the differentiation operator on $Trig_N$ and $T = D^2 + 2D$. What is the matrix of T relative to the basis ${e^{int}}|n|\le N$ ?

I know that for a normal polynomial space, the basis is $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^k\}$ and the matrix for $D: f \to f'$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&2&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&0&3&\ldots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&0&\cdots&k\\0&0&0&0&\ldots&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ from

$D(1)=0$, $D(x)=1$,$\cdots$, $D(x^k)=kx^{k-1}$. But in this case the basis is much more complicated and it would be hard to derive the derivative matrix like above, let alone the matrix of $T=D^2+D$. Is there a different way to figure out the associated matrix of T?

Comment: The best way forward is to simply use the same process. It might look complicated, but the basis is actually chosen to make the form of the matrix very simple (in fact, diagonal!).

Comment: got it thank you,i dont really recall differentiations on complex numbers can you provide a few examples of derivatives on the above operation and ill follow your examples to figure out the entire matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, for each $n\in\Bbb N$,$$(D^2+2D)(e^{int})=D(ine^{int})+2ine^{int}=(-n^2+2in)e^{int}.$$Therefore, if your vbasis is $\left\{e^{-iNt},e^{-i(N-1)t},\ldots,e^{iNt}\right\}$, then the matrix that your after is the diagonal matrix such that the entries of the main diagonal are$$-N^2-2iN,-(N-1)^2-2i(N-1),\ldots,-N^2+2iN.$$

Comment: thank you, why is the vbasis's power N, not n $\le$N?

Comment: You stated in your question that $|n|\leqslant N$. So, the possible values for $n$ are $-N$, $-N+1$, …, $N$.